# publishInstallAsync NullPointer Exception

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I use the [Facebook SDK 3.0.2](https://developers.facebook.com/android/) and want to publish app installs for campaigns through this SDK. I do not want to provide a facebook login, just publish app installs and also log events. I followed this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/mobile-app-ads/), i.e., I registered the app with Facebook and added all the stuff like package name, class name and key hashes (both dev and publish key hashes).

The install events is registered fine from the ios SDK. But if I try to call `com.facebook.Settings.publishInstallAsync(context, MY_APP_ID);` in the android app, I get a logCat message `NullPointerException: null` with the tag `Facebook-publish`; moreover no install events are visible in the App Dashboard for android devices. If the device does not have the native Facebook app installed on the device I also get a `Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider` message in logcat before the `NullPointerException: null` message.
Did anybody get install events working on android?

Comment: It seems like the facebook app needs to be installed and a facebook user needs to be logged in as well to get `publishInstallAsync` working. This is strange, as it could be possible that a facebook user is only browsing facebook on his browser on the device and get an ad displayed that redirects to the play store. In this case, the install events get lost..

Comment: I also use `com.facebook.Settings.publishInstallAsync(context, MY_APP_ID);` of SDK 3.0.2 in my app without login. It works for me. Please, show the full logcat message and the exact place where the `NullPointerException` occurs

Comment: @sromku The exception is caught by the facebook SDK and only printed to logcat as `NullPointerException: null`. It happens in the `publishInstallAndWaitForResponse` method in `com.facebook.Settings` at the `publishParams.setProperty(ATTRIBUTION_KEY, attributionId);` call, because attributionId is null. This note in the app dashboard section that explains this behaviour: 
*An app install is reported when users are running and logged in to a newer version of the Facebook mobile app (e.g. >= 5.0 on iOS, >= 1.9.8 on Android) and a version of your native mobile app that reports install analytics.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so the problem occurs due to the fact that you don't have Facebook application installed on your device.

From the [**source code**](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/Settings.java#L358) of `publishInstallAndWaitForResponse(Context,String)` method you can see this line:

`String attributionId = Settings.getAttributionId(context.getContentResolver());`

In the `getAttributionId(ContentResolver)` is said:

```
returns null if the facebook app is not present on the phone
```

So, this is the problem. You get null for `attributionId` and thus publishing installs doesn't for for you.

Comment: Actually the null pointer exception happens also if no user is logged in (not attribution id can be found), as mentioned already in my comment. If no FB app is installed on the device, `Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider` is shown as error first.  Thanks for the summary; still install events on a device with logged out FB users are lost (e.g. FB user is using the browser instead) which is a shame..

Comment: I totally forget this, the answer and the comment are both correct!